# 302 redirect, Tomcat behind Apache for hybris

Tags: apache2, tomcat

I've configured hybris and apache, mod_jk using [this blog article](http://www.facebook.com/permalink.php?id=317609748375071&story_fbid=680730588729650).

hybris is completely running fine on tomcat ports http on 9001 and https on 9002.

One developer has also configured redirection at hybris level so any request for `http://hot.local:9001/` gets automatically redirected to `https://hot.local:9002/abc/en`.

Now I'm stuck at apache and `mod_jk` configuration point of view. I'm not able to setup URL redirection in apache with `mod_jk` configuration. Getting below error:

```
[22993:22208] [debug] jk_handler::mod_jk.c (2047): Service finished with status=302 for worker=tss1
```

Comment: help will be great appreciable.....

Answer (score 0):

1)  Opened Port 443 exclusively in ubuntu

2)  Include redirectPort="8443" in server.xml

3)  Include below tag in apache2 ssl config
    JkMountCopy On

Thanks
G